# How to hide the yellow console.logs in nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Is it possible to hide the yellow logs that displays when you start en watch with nodemon?

below is displayed in yellow in the console.

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: /var/www/test/server/core/src/**/*
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From the documentation returned by `nodemon -h`:

> -q, --quiet .............. minimise nodemon messages to start/stop only.

So run:

```
nodemon --quiet your-file.js
```

Comment: Works perfectly in nodemon@2.0.4, is not listed in the help.

Comment: It looks like the options are now more hidden, but still there, in `nodemon --help options` . This command is listed at the bottom of `nodemon -h`.  https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1160

Comment: T.Hanks for the hint. I completely overread the command `nodemon --help options`!

Comment: 1.5 years after: they dont add this flag to docs or examples and peoples need to go to SO to find this flag... nice UX

Comment: Or for those that are using the `nodemon.json` file, you can simply add:

`{ "quiet": true }`